# dynamic RNN using tensorflow with longitudinal data with variable sequence

Tags: tensorflow

The question I have is that for longitudinal data for patients, the data looks like the following:

```
patientID covariate1 covariate2 outcome time points
0001      5          6          0        1
0001      6          7          0        2
0001      4          5          0        3
0001      6          5          1        4
0002      4          4          0        1
0002      1          2          0        2
0003      2          7          0        1
0003      5          3          0        2
0003      8          9          1        3
```

This is more like sequence binary classification and I want to use **RNN** to do that. since for each patient, the longitudinal history length is different, how can we implement the dynamic RNN here?
Another big question is that how can we convert that data form to a tensor with variable length vectors in one of its dimensions? (not a perfect cubed tensor)